# Can we declare class properties conditionally in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, class

In Angular can we declare optional properties using safe navigation operator. I am looking a way is there is an option we can declare properties like below

```
class IUser{
  name: string
  username: string
  mob: string
  email: string
  uniqID: string
}
```

Is there is any method in angular show that it can be like either name, username, mob is mandatory or email and uniqID.

I have tried looking for this but not able to find so posting here. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Interface? Usually a better choice than a class anyways..

Comment: Angular no, typescript maybe. Check utility types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html